# Not sure how to incorporate this into my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is supposed to spit out this format: 'Last Name, First Name M.I.'
BUT... If the middle initial is just a single letter (e.g. name = "Bala X Krish"), it should NOT put a period after the M.I. (should return "Krish, Bala X").

Right now, my code is returning 'Krish, Bala X.'

How can I fix it so that only during this specific instance of a single-letter M.I., the end period is NOT added?

```
def modify(name):
    """
    name is a string with zero or more spaces
    with one space between each "word"
    return string "last, first MI. MI. MI. ..."
    where MI is middle initial
    """
    NameLst = name.split() 

    MiddleNames = NameLst[1:-1]

    initial = ""

    if " " not in name:
        return name
    elif name.count(" ") == 1:
        return NameLst[-1] + ", " + NameLst[0]
    else:
        MiddleNameCount = len(MiddleNames)
        for MiddleName in MiddleNames:
            Keep = MiddleName[0] + "."
            if MiddleNameCount == 1: 
                    initial = initial + Keep + " "
            elif MiddleNameCount > 1:
                    if MiddleName[0:-2]:
                        initial = initial + Keep + " "
                    elif MiddleName[-1]:
                        initial = initial + Keep
        x = NameLst[-1] + ", " + NameLst[0] + " " + initial 
        return x[0:-1]
```

Comment: If you give it the name "Bala X Krish" or "Bala Xzibit Krish" they both return the same thing i.e. `Krish, Bala X.` What are you trying to accomplish? If you can give some input and output examples of what you are expecting, I could try helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is way to complicate for this task.
You can simply itterate over the middleNames and check their length:

```py
def modify(name):
    """
    name is a string with zero or more spaces
    with one space between each "word"
    return string "last, first MI. MI. MI. ..."
    where MI is middle initial
    """
    nameLst = name.split()
    if len(nameLst) < 2:
        return name

    middleNames = nameLst[1:-1]

    initial = f"{nameLst[-1]}, {nameLst[0]}"

    for i in middleNames:
        initial += f" {i[0]}"
        if len(i) != 1: initial += '.'

    return initial
```

Please remeber that the use of f-Strings (`f""`) for formatting is only available in python 3.6+, so you may want to use `.format()` depending on the environment.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to change this line:

```
Keep = MiddleName[0] + "."
```

to this:

```
Keep = MiddleName[0]
if len(MiddleName) > 1: Keep += "."
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and made it way shorted to achieve your desired result in a clean and minimal way. Hope this helps.

```
def handle_middle_name(name):
    if len(name.split()) == 3:

        first, middle, last = name.split()[0], name.split()[1], name.split()[-1]
        formatted_name = f"{last}, {first} {middle[0] + '.' if len(middle) > 1 else middle[0]}"

        return formatted_name

    else:
        return "Your name doesn't have a middle name"

name = input("Enter your full name (including middle name): ")
print(handle_middle_name(name))
```

Comment: Your lines are way to long, you should have a look at the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)